# msbuild.exe suddenly freezes

Tags: c#, msbuild, freeze

I'm having issues when building a C# project with msbuild.exe, it freezes. Looking at the msbuild.exe process in Process Explorer, I get something like this:

```
MSBuild.exe
    |
    +--csc.exe
          |
          +--cvtres.exe
```

It's very weird as it's not constantly reproducible but when it does, it's always at cvtres.exe.
If I kill cvtres.exe, it gives me a message saying

```
'[PROJECT_PATH]\obj\Release\[TEMP_FILE_NAME].tmp' is not a valid Win32 resource file
```

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: do you have any anti-virus/anti-spam app running in the background by any chance? you may want to white-list cvtres.exe.

Comment: muratgu, we do. Are you saying the AV can sometimes block and sometimes not block a process?

Comment: daisuke: just a hunch. try white-listing the exe and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this out. It was because I had an old version of Visual Studio (namely 2003) installed.
It adds environment variables "LIB" and "INCLUDE" with values for .NET 1.1 (to your System variables not User!!). Removing them resolved the issue.

Comment: This may not be the only reason. I am still getting the same issue albeit less frequently. I am reintalling the .NET Framework.

Comment: And re-installing .NET (from 1.1 all the way up to 4.0) didn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe cvtres is used to compile your resource files. Maybe you have a lot of resources, or  the resources being compiled are large or invalid?

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's a comment offering a suggestion. You might want to post it as a comment instead.